# Pandas/Seaborn KeyError: '[example]' not in index

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

Sorry in advance for poor formatting, new to python and to posting on this site.

I use the following code to get the dataframe below:

```
staff=df.loc['Adults in my after school program are nice.':'I like the adults in my after school program.', 'Percent':'Performance']

Prompt                                        Percent        Performance
Adults are nice.                              87             Good
Adults treat me fairly.                       70             Needs Improvement
Adults listen to what I have to say.          90             Excellent
I like the adults.                            80             Good
```

I am trying to plot it using Seaborn with this code:

```
fg = seaborn.FacetGrid(data=df, hue='Performance', aspect=1.61)
fg.map(plt.bar, 'Staff', 'Percent').add_legend()
fg
```

However, it always gives me the error

> KeyError: "['Staff'] not in index"

when I try to plot.  I've tested it using

```
'Prompt' in staff.index
```

which returns `True`

I've also tried resetting the index, but that doesn't seem to help either.  Any thoughts as to what might be wrong with my code?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your dataframe has no column labeled "staff". What did you expected to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well its unclear what exactly you want to plot out of the dataframe, but there might be easier ways.

if its just a bar plot, you could just:

```
 sns.barplot(data=staff, y='column name you want to associate to y', x='column name you want to associate to x, if any', hue='hue you want to apply if any')
```

there are a couple misstakes in your code, which are kind of since you are new, let me help make em clear:

- first, you make a new df, called staff. afterwards, you refer to df instead of staff, that might be a mistake
- second, you are first creating a grid, to afterwards try to apply a map function to try to graph on it, which is not really the most common/simple way to plot a graph
- third, inside the map function, you are passing your arguments all wrong

a good hint would be for you to check some example plot functions, either from seaborn, or matplotlib documentation, here are some referals:

http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

hope it helps